# batch script for delete empty .dat files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to delete all .dat extension files with file size of 0. I have developed the following batch script but don't working well. Could you please help me to sort this out.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET OLD_ZIPS=C:\Users\dkbdodanwala\Desktop\s\*.dat


:deleteFiles
for /f "tokens=1* delims=;" %%A in ("%OLD_ZIPS%") do (
    if exist "%%A" if %%~zA==0 (
    DEL "%%A"
    )
    set OLD_ZIPS=%%B
)
```

Comment: A bit confused by your code.  It looks like you are trying to get a directory list of .dat files but you can't do it like that with a `FOR /F` command.  You would need to use the `DIR` command within the `FOR /F` command.  Also I don't see why you are using a semicolon as a delimiter.  Are you saying your file names have semicolons in the name?

Comment: Sorry my bad. using this script i can delete all the empty files with .dat extension but when there is a non empty files script is not working.

Comment: There is no reason for using a `for /F` loop, a standard `for` loop is all you need: `for %%A in ("C:\Users\dkbdodanwala\Desktop\s\*.dat") do if %%~zA equ 0 del "%%~A"`

Comment: Your code does not check that all .dat files are 0 bytes.  It only checks if the first .dat file in the folder is 0 bytes and then globally deletes ALL .dat files.  Your `SET` command for using variable %%B still makes no sense in your code.

Comment: @ECHO OFF
SET OLD_ZIPS=C:\Users\dkbdodanwala\Desktop\s\*.dat


for %%A in ("%OLD_ZIPS%") do If %%~zA equ 0 del %%A             Came up with this one. Is this correct?

Comment: @user3582678, why don't you test it.

Comment: Working fine for me. Thanks for the help. Just wanted to make sure its correct.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a `For` loop if you use `WMIC` instead:

```dos
WMIC DataFile Where "Drive='C:' And Path='\\Users\\dkbdodanwala\\Desktop\\s\\' And Extension='dat' And FileSize='0'" Call Delete
```

Comment: Working Thanks a lot for the help.